# Vertical center menu using foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Here is a demo: [demo](https://codepen.io/gmcamposano/pen/EpwRGM)

I just want to know, using foundation simple menu, how can I align it vertically. I am new to this so if my question is kindda dumb, my apologies:

Code here:

```
<nav>
        <ul class="menu expanded align-center">
            <li class="image"><i class="fab fa-cloudversify fa-3x"></i></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i></i><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        </ul>  
</nav>
```

Css:

```
ul li {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Library:
Foundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding flex to the `a` tag and making sure it fully fits inside the `li`-element, will allow you to position the text.

See my pen for the example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyPMVx

.html

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu expanded align-center">

<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        </ul>  
</nav>
```

.css

```
ul li {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
.menu.expanded a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully, but it seems to leave the icon not in line with the a tags. Thank you for your help. Remember my code initially had a logo (which i am using an icon to start out)

Comment: If you want, you can post the code with the icon, maybe a `justify-content: center` will suffice

Comment: Great to hear. Nowadays flex is the way to go for position subitems.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```css
.menu-centered {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-centered.vertical > li {
 margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation-flex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu-centered vertical">
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi rajib, thank you for your time. Sadly it is not working because it is a horizontal navbar.

Comment: You are looking for the vertical menu. Your question related to vertical, not Horizontal.